# How to use a jsonb column with H2, JPA, and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, h2

Using Spring, when I try running my integration tests don't work because the H2 database can't create the table. This is the error:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table foo (id binary not null, bar jsonb, primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement
```

My entity being defined as follow :

```
@Entity(name = "foo")
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private UUID id;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private Object bar;
}
```

My type being defined through `com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52:2.14.0`.

And my h2 version being `com.h2database:h2:2.0.202`.

If I remove the `bar` property, it works fine.

Any clue please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jsonb` is a PostgreSQL data type, not available in H2. It differs from PG's `json` data type in that internally it is stored in a binary structure that is more suitable for some operations and indexing.

H2 does have a `json` format, though https://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#json_type

Answer (score 3):

You can create a  JSONB domain in H2 and use it.

If you want to use H2 as  the testing database in your Spring application that runs on Postgresql, adding the following to the connection string provides JSONB type.

```
jdbc:h2:mem:public;MODE=PostgreSQL;INIT=CREATE DOMAIN IF NOT EXISTS JSONB AS JSON;
```

For JPA you will need to configure custom read and write converters separately for runtime and for testing.

Uses `PGObject` in Postgresql converters and `byte[]` in H2 converters. There should be enough answers on  Stackoverflow about creating custom converters for JPA.

Comment: If you know the right keywords to search for or have a link, this would be most helpful.